# Appinventor - finding the launch icon / starting appinventor

Tags: android, app-inventor

Could someone explain how to start Appinventor after installing?

I downloaded the file and placed in folder as indicated in the provided instructions but am unable to find the launching icon for the Appinventor editor.

http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/about/

Comment: isn't there an installer? Or do you have a problem with the drivers?

Comment: i dont what the problem is..
in appinventor-extras folder i have adb.exe,emulator,mksdcard and other folders..
where will will i find the icon that launches its editor.

Comment: This question is obsolete now, as the version of Appinventor which it refers to is not available any longer and the Appinventor 2 does not need to be installed any more. Problem is: The question refers to version 1, the answers mostly to version 2. This has to be sorted out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sign up for an invitation. That is just the extras folder. Go to the main page, submit your email, and wait.

Comment: this was in 2010 with invitation only. Now everybody can use it. Just go to http://appinventor.mit.edu/ for details

Answer (score 2):

go to [beta.appinventor.mit.edu](http://beta.appinventor.mit.edu) and sign up if you haven't already. Download the setup provided in the 'support'. This download just supports functioning of the blocks editor and emulator (virtual device). 
there isn't any icon on your PC, you need to go to the earlier mentioned link and that is your workspace - all on the cloud.

earlier answer from Blaze:
of course they can be placed on the Play Store. Why not?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an icon like say MS Word or Excel. It's based on the web. So you go to http://www.appinventorbeta.com/about/ and log in to your Google Account and start creating an app from there. All your projects are stored on the web, so you can work on them where ever you are.

Answer (score 0):

This questions refers to Appinventor version 1 which had to be installed on the client. This version 1 is not available any longer, Version 2 is a web service and requires no installation at all.

The Appinventor main page is here: http://appinventor.mit.edu

and the Application for creating Apps here: http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu

You only need to register with a Google Account in order to start.

Maybe the whole question should be removed as it is some kind of misleading?

Answer (score -1):

Just sign up for a google ID (if you don't already have one) and google it (or go to the more selection under the "More>>" menu)

I believe that the apps made by the AppInventor cannot be places on the Android Market, I know this from personal experience

Comment: in the beginning of App Inventor that was not possible but it is meanwhile.